# Relative formulas in Excel using Tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel provides a table range now whereby you can automatically work in a table. I have noticed that the formulas work a little differently. Whilst I can get the normal formulas to work. I am struggling to get the @ColumnName reference to be a fixed reference.  see below

[image]

Does anyone know what this style of reference is used for, why I would not use the normal style formulas and how to define a fixed reference for this reference style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table syntax makes reading your formulas much easier in general - assuming you use meaningful column name (in row 1 in your example). It also makes your models more robust.

However, it'll "lock" your column, so copying it to the left or right will not shift it - so there is not option similar to `B$1`.

Here's the strange thing: if you drag the formula to the right with the mouse, the formula will actually adjust. If you use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> instead, the reference will stay locked to the column.

Alternatively, you can still use the normal references, so just use this here if you need it.

Comment: Great, thats what I thought, I was thinking that there may have been a solution.

Comment: See my update - funnily enough I just stumbled across a way to do what you're looking today... :-)